# SQL Query to get name of all employees under a manager recursively

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking for a query to get name of all employees under a particular manager recursively.

**EMP_TABLE**

```
EMP_ID     EMP_NAME     MANAGER_ID
1          A            3
2          B            3
3          C            4
4          D            5
5          E            NULL
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, MANAGER_ID FROM EMP_TABLE WHERE MANAGER_ID=4;
```

**Output of this query:**

```
EMP_ID     EMP_NAME     MANAGER_ID
3          C            4
```

**Expected output:**

```
EMP_ID     EMP_NAME     MANAGER_ID
1          A            3
2          B            3
3          C            4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use CONNECT BY to process hierarchical data in the table:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/connect-by.html

```
SELECT EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, MANAGER_ID FROM EMP_TABLE 
START WITH MANAGER_ID=4
CONNECT BY MANAGER_ID = prior EMP_ID
ORDER BY EMP_ID;

+--------+----------+------------+
| EMP_ID | EMP_NAME | MANAGER_ID |
+--------+----------+------------+
|      1 | A        |          3 |
|      2 | B        |          3 |
|      3 | C        |          4 |
+--------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: Gokhan Atil OMG! You are great. Really great answer. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `CONNECT BY` solution is very clear.

Here you have a recursive solution:

```
WITH rec AS (
    SELECT EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, MANAGER_ID 
      FROM EMP_TABLE 
     WHERE MANAGER_ID=4
     UNION ALL
    SELECT tb.EMP_ID, tb.EMP_NAME, tb.MANAGER_ID 
      FROM rec AS ta
      JOIN EMP_TABLE AS tb ON ta.EMP_ID = tb.MANAGER_ID
)
SELECT EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, MANAGER_ID 
  FROM rec
 ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple query
SELECT * FROM EMP_TABLE WHERE MANAGER_ID IS NOT NULL

Comment: Abhay S: how will your query work in case of manager_id=5. My question is for recursive result.

Comment: if you need recursive result then this doc Help you. this query for simple result
https://haughtcodeworks.com/blog/software-development/recursive-sql-queries-using-ctes/

SELECT* FROM EMP_TABLE 
START WITH MANAGER_ID=5
CONNECT BY MANAGER_ID = prior EMP_ID
ORDER BY EMP_ID;